# Unicode error only when code run with -n flag at the command-line

Tags: regex, unicode, command-line, perl

The following simple script (basically) slurps in its input, splits it according to a regexp, replaces all newlines in each element of the resulting list, and prints out the modified elements one-by-one:

```
# demo.pl
use strict;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use warnings qw(FATAL utf8);

BEGIN { $/ = $\ = undef; }

while ( <> ) {
  s/\n\z//;
  s/\n/\\n/g, print "$_\n" for split /\n(?=[^\W\d]\w*=)/;
}
```

When given an input file (`INPUTFILE`) with the following (UTF8-encoded) contents as its argument

```
A=42
ΦΡΩΒΩΖΖ=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
_B_C_D12=
foo
345bar=nope
baz
  =whatever=
X_Y_Z=quux
```

...it prints out the desired output, namely:

```
% perl demo.pl INPUTFILE
A=42
ΦΡΩΒΩΖΖ=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
_B_C_D12=\nfoo\n345bar=nope\nbaz\n  =whatever=
X_Y_Z=quux
```

In contrast, the following almost identical CLI one-liner

```
% perl -ne 'use strict; use utf8; use open qw(:std :utf8); use warnings qw(FATAL utf8); BEGIN { $/ = $\ = undef; } s/\n\z//; s/\n/\\n/g, print "$_\n" for split /\n(?=[^\W\d]\w*=)/;' INPUTFILE
```

...produces the following for the same input file

```
A=42\nÎ¦Î¡Î©ÎÎ©ÎÎ=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
_B_C_D12=\nfoo\n345bar=nope\nbaz\n  =whatever=
X_Y_Z=quux
```

There are (apparently) two problems here:

1. the regular expression fails to separate the first and second items;
2. the output contains an illegible substring.

(I expect that both problems will have the same underlying cause.)

---

The only difference between the "in-file script" (`demo.pl`) and the CLI one-liner is that the former explicitly wraps the body of the script with `while ( <> ) { ... }`, whereas for the latter, the `-n` flag causes this wrapper to be inserted automatically.

**Q:** How must the one-liner above be modified so that it produces the desired result *with the `-n` flag*?

---

BTW, not surprisingly, the *exact* command-line equivalent of `demo.pl` (without the `-n` flag), namely

```
% perl -e 'use strict; use utf8; use open qw(:std :utf8); use warnings qw(FATAL utf8); BEGIN { $/ = $\ = undef; } while ( <> ) { s/\n\z//; s/\n/\\n/g, print "$_\n" for split /\n(?=[^\W\d]\w*=)/; }' INPUTFILE
```

also produces the desired output.

So the problem, whatever it is, has something to do with the `-n` flag.

---

FWIW:

```
% perl -v | head -2

This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

---

EDIT: One more clue: if the input to the failing one-liner is passed through `STDIN` rather than as a filename in `@ARGV` (e.g. replace `INPUTFILE` with `< INPUTFILE`), then it produces <s>the desired output</s> fully legible, **though still incorrect**, output:

```
A=42\nΦΡΩΒΩΖΖ=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
_B_C_D12=\nfoo\n345bar=nope\nbaz\n  =whatever=
X_Y_Z=quux
```

My current guess is that `use open qw(:std :utf8)` does not cover the input stream that `<>` reads from when the input is passed as a filename in `@ARGV`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only difference between the "in-file script" (demo.pl) and the CLI one-liner is that the former explicitly wraps the body of the script with while ( <> ) { ... }, whereas for the latter, the -n flag causes this wrapper to be inserted automatically.

Yes, exactly — `-n` wraps *all* the code in `while (<>) { ... }`. That includes your `use utf8;` and `use open(:utf8);` lines, so **the file is already open by the time you enable Unicode**.

You can easily validate this by running the equivalent program to the `-n` version:

```
while (<>) {
    # demo.pl
    use strict;
    use utf8;
    use open qw(:std :utf8);
    use warnings qw(FATAL utf8);
    BEGIN { $/ = $\ = undef; }
    s/\n\z//;
    s/\n/\\n/g, print "$_\n" for split /\n(?=[^\W\d]\w*=)/;
}
```

and seeing the same effect.

---

More interestingly, you can see that the `use` declarations do still have an effect: run the exact same input file through twice

```
perl demo.pl INPUTFILE INPUTFILE
```

and you get two outputs, the first one broken, the second one correct. That also happens with your one-liner.

---

You can enable UTF-8 for input by default using the [`-C` flag with the `i`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-[_number/list_]*) (8) option:

```
perl -CiO -ne 'use strict; use utf8; BEGIN { $/ = $\ = undef; } s/\n\z//; s/\n/\\n/g, print "$_\n" for split /\n(?=[^\W\d]\w*=)/;' INPUTFILE
```

That ensures that UTF-8 is enabled before the file is opened, and you get the correct output. The `O` enables UTF-8 for standard output as well, so that you can print it.

Comment: This is confusing.  My understanding was that `use ...` implies a `BEGIN { ... }`.  I thought this meant that it would happen before any of the rest of the code is processed...

Comment: Thanks.  FWIW, the version you show with only `-Ci` (as opposed to `-CiO`) fails with the input given in the question, due to the `use warnings qw(FATAL utf8)` together with the presence of wide characters in the output.  Getting rid of the `use warnings qw(FATAL utf8)` allows the program to finish, but still a warning gets printed.  Bottom-line: it has to be `-CiO`, not `-Ci`.

Comment: `use` is a bit magical some of the time. Good point about the warnings - edited now.

Comment: OP: Note that you can also include required modules at the CLI prior to the `-e|-E` switch: `perl -Mstrict -Mopen=:std,:utf8 -Mwarnings=FATAL,utf8 -e 'BEGIN{...`. (posted as comment as to not take away from this answer).